# Generar múltiples carpetas a partir de lista

Tags: pandas, bucle-for, mkdir

No entiendo por que motivo el for no genera las carpetas que le indico en el Vector. Si aplico el codigo uno a uno funciona, pero al implementar el ciclo for el código arroja error:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
Carpeta = 'C:/Users/Rodolfo/Desktop/Nueva carpeta/Nueva carpeta'
Excel = 'C:/Users/Rodolfo/Desktop/Nueva carpeta/Nueva carpeta/LM 5 de febrero.xlsx'
Vector = pd.read_excel(Excel, sheet_name='LM', usecols=['NOMBRE'])
Vector = Vector.drop_duplicates()
for i in Vector:
    Ruta = Carpeta + '/' + Vector['NOMBRE'][i]
    try:
        os.mkdir(Ruta)
    except FileExistsError:
        pass
```

Comment: cual es el error?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar asegurarte de que sea `str` así:

```py
    Ruta = Carpeta + '/' + str(Vector['NOMBRE'][i])
```

El error es que estás iterando mal `pd.DataFrame`, por lo menos depende de como es el excel. La recomendación general es usar `Vector.iterrows()`:

```py
import os
import pandas as pd
Carpeta = os.getcwd()
Excel = 'a.xlsx'
Vector = pd.read_excel(Excel, sheet_name='LM', usecols=['NOMBRE'])
Vector = Vector.drop_duplicates()
for i,row in Vector.iterrows():
    Ruta = Carpeta + '/' + str(row['NOMBRE'])
    try:
        os.mkdir(Ruta)
    except FileExistsError:
        pass
```

Similar a como lo estabas usando sería:

```py
import os
import pandas as pd
Carpeta = os.getcwd()
Excel = 'a.xlsx'
Vector = pd.read_excel(Excel, sheet_name='LM', usecols=['NOMBRE'])
Vector = Vector.drop_duplicates()
for i,row in Vector.iterrows():
    Ruta = Carpeta + '/' + str(Vector['NOMBRE'][i])
    try:
        os.mkdir(Ruta)
    except FileExistsError:
        pass
```

Comment: Amigo, creía haber respondido hace tiempo. Bueno, le agradezco, me soluciono el problema